# Stop countdown when page is not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I am new to JavaScript and I want to have a countdown that automatically starts when the page loads, and only resume if the page is focused. Here is an example `http://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/mz7z5/`.

How can I use this same logic in `setTimeout(function() {});` ?

This is my script:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    var timeleft = 20;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
        timeleft -= 1;
        if (timeleft < 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "20 sec done";
        }
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 22000);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: sir you are not read my full question if page is load the countdown is start and if page is blur or focusout then countdown pause not end and if user back again on the pagr then countdown resume not restart

Comment: What stops you from implementing the suggested answers into your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `$(window).blur()` and `$(window).focus()` to `clearInterval` and `setInterval`.Try this
Unfotunately **its not working in the snippet** but works fine outside of snippet

```js
let downloadTimer;
var timeleft = 20;
downloadTimer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

function countDown() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
    timeleft -= 1;
    if (timeleft < 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "20 sec done";
    }
}

$(window).blur(function() {
    console.log("blurred");
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
})
$(window).focus(function() {
    console.log("focuesed");
    downloadTimer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: sir its initialy start on page load but if i am open another tab it not stop it is run continuously your ans is not work

Comment: @Techno Harsh this is not working in this `snippet` just go and use it in a seperate file. Its working.

Comment: ok sir it work how i can apply same logic in `setTimeout(function() {
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 22000);`   see live in my website `http://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/mz7z5/`

Comment: @Techno Harsh accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @TechnoHarsh it's totally unclear why the 22000 and what you need to do with that button. If you need to pause that one too use the same/similar logic. C'mon do some coding on your own! It's fun.

Comment: ok sir thanks         ..